# XML Parsing - XPath expression trying to access xml elements inside second for loop

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that I am trying to parse and store as objects so that I can persist them.

```
<key>Playlists</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key><string>Library</string>
        <key>Master</key><true/>
        <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>1806</integer>
        <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>29E12A03204E0722</string>
        <key>Visible</key><false/>
        <key>All Items</key><true/>
        <key>Playlist Items</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>1234</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>1282</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>1694</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>1558</integer>
            </dict>
       </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key><string>Music</string>
        <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>2687</integer>
        <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>29E12A03204E072C</string>
        <key>Distinguished Kind</key><integer>4</integer>
        <key>Music</key><true/>
        <key>All Items</key><true/>
        <key>Playlist Items</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>1234</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>1282</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>1694</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Track ID</key><integer>1558</integer>
            </dict>
       </array>
    </dict>
```

I'm having trouble accessing the second array. It keeps displaying track Id's from the first array in every playlist.

It is doing this for all the playlists I am trying to display.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: question related with same input : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34106517/dom-accessing-inner-elements-of-the-same-name-in-java/34106629#34106629

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
NodeList tList = (NodeList)x.evaluate("/plist/dict/array/dict/array/dict", root, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

to

```
NodeList tList = (NodeList)x.evaluate("array/dict", dict, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Still showing the same numbers in every playlist.